# Correcting offset between LiDAR datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, remote-sensing, georeferencing, lidar

I am analyzing multiple LiDAR datasets looking at the changes between pre-wildfire and post-wildfire topography. The datatsets are of the same general location. I did not acquire the datasets on my own, so I am not the one who originally reduced the raw data from the instrument, which is part of my issue as I was not the one to verify the horizontal control.

The problem that I am having is that the datasets are, in general, slightly offset from one another. This poses a major problem for generating a comparison (raster subtraction) looking at elevation change. When I process such a comparison, the offset is more apparent on south facing slopes because they are steeper. I have included an illustration of my issue below. As is evident, the south facing slopes show a characteristic false positive change in elevation and the north facing slopes show a characteristic false negative change in elevation, though it is less drastic because the north facing slopes are not as steep.

I am hopeful that someone with experience can shed some light on a possible solution to this issue. Of course, the datasets can be shifted using the georeferencing toolbar, but I would just be guessing at the correct shift. I am looking for a systematic way of handling the shift. [image]

Comment: Are you comparing bare earth elevations?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall yes, bare earth. Both datasets are rasterized at the same resolution, using the same interpolation method and in the same GCS.

Comment: What cell size are you using? What are the horizontal and vertical accuracy statements for *both* datasets? The common mistake between sensors and even runs is to try and get your cell size as small as possible, the uncertainty values need to be *added* not *averaged*, using a cell size less than the sum of the horizontal uncertainty is asking for trouble - in reality your cell size should be more than quadruple. Any differences between the DEM values less than the sum of the vertical uncertainty is *noise* and should be ignored.

Comment: It should be possible to implement a 'difference minimizing offset calculation'. A bayesian optimization with x and y shifts as inputs and the difference between the rasters as output. Fun times.

Comment: @MichaelStimson unfortunately I do not have the accuracy statement for one of the datasets. The accuracy statement for the other only provides RMSz values. The acquisitioner (Sanborn Map Company) makes no mention of how they established horizontal control. Regardless, I have produced DEMs at many resolutions to try an account for this, but there doesn't seem to be a sweet spot for minimizing the error.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen That it not a calculation or process that I am familiar with. Can you elaborate a bit more on the methodology? If my limited understanding is correct, it goes something like: insert a table of x and y shifts to run on the two DEMs and the function will solve for the pair of offsets that minimizes the difference between the two? Keep in mind that their is a good deal of change in the datasets as one is pre-wildfire and debris flow and the other is post... Perhaps I could run it on a specific area where I expect only error in the comparison?

Comment: When comparing two datasets global realignment is the first step, you could try with the raster but look for well defined areas (edges of asphalt, concrete or rock, waterway junctions for X,Y if you're desperate) and distribute your control as evenly as possible trying to focus on the ephemera, the theory is that by making the edges fit the internal area should be forced into place. You could consider it as an alternate georeference to tighten up the matching. This does not improve your accuracy though, just the alignment, sensor and GPS errors are still the same.